# "Choose items" tool fails to load items and makes Visual Studio 17.7.1 restart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2022, toolbox

I recently updated my Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.7.1.

The problem is that when I right-click the Toolbox to select `Choose items...`, the popup window appears for a moment, then Visual Studio just restarts without indicating anything.

I have tried to run Visual Studio as administrator and reset the toolbox, but nothing changed.

It could be failing when loading one of the components.

Comment: `17.7.1` is a big update. Have you restated the machine after? If it fails again after that, then reset the Toolbox using a clean Project -- What were you adding through the `Choose Toolbox Items` tool?

Comment: it doesn't give any chance to add anything just , Choose toolbox items window fail and visual studio restart it self

Comment: My question was more about: *why are you trying to use that tool?*, i.e., *did you use this tool to add some references earlier? (before the update)* -- As mentioned, restart the machine if you haven't already, create a clean Project, try to use the `Choose item` tool. If it still fails, open up the installer, select `More->Repair`. If it still doesn't work, reinstall the whole thing -- I have the same version installed and I see no problem with it. Probably something went wrong on your side, I can't say what